# Insert signature into threaded mail in mail.app

Tags: mail.app, signature

When I get a threaded message in mail.app and want to insert my signature under my reply text, then the signature gets inserted at the bottom of the email content.

Is it possible to insert the mail signature just below the reply text I wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the setting you're looking for.  It will always put your sig above quoted text.

Mail -> Preferences, Signatures.

[image: SIGNATURE-ABOVE QUOTED TEXT]

Comment: Gosh! Sometimes mac os x can be to simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to this question (apologies, can't comment w/18 rep), why is it not possible to **choose** to have the signature at the top or the bottom for individual replies? For some, I would like the signature before the quoted text; for others, I'd like the signature after.